# My API is getting called 2 times In Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am working in my Ionic Project and my API is getting called 2 times. I am not able to get why my API is getting called 2 times.

This is my **productdetails.html**:

```
<ion-col *ngIf="hassizenot && product.out_of_stock == 0" style="padding: 0px;">
      <button class="mybtn11" (click)="addtocartnew(product)" ion-button small>
        Add to Cart
      </button>
</ion-col>
```

This is my **productdetails.ts**:

```
addtocartnew(detailsp)
{
this.storage.get("ID").then((val) =>
    {
      if(val)
      { 
        if(detailsp.SelectedSize)
        {
          let usercartnewdetails = {
            user_id: val,
            product_id: detailsp.id,
            size: detailsp.SelectedSize,
          };
          this.restProvider.usercartproducts(usercartnewdetails, 'user_cart/'+detailsp.id+'/'+val+'/'+detailsp.SelectedSize).subscribe((data) => {
            if (data) {
              console.log("One");
              this.responseEdit = data;
              console.log(this.responseEdit.msg);
              if (this.responseEdit.status === 'success') {
                this.presentToast(detailsp.product_name);
              }
              else{
                this.presentToasterror();
              }
            }
          });
        }
        else
        {
          let usercartnewdetails = {
            user_id: val,
            product_id: detailsp.id,
          };
          this.restProvider.usercartproducts(usercartnewdetails, 'user_cart/'+detailsp.id+'/'+val).subscribe((data) => {
            if (data) {
              console.log("Two");
              this.responseEdit = data;
              console.log(this.responseEdit.msg);
              if (this.responseEdit.status === 'success') {
                this.presentToast(detailsp.product_name);
              }
              else{
                this.presentToasterror();
              }
            }
          });
        }
      }
    });
}
```

This is my **Service**:

```
usercartproducts(credentials, type) {
  var headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin' , '*');
  headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT');
  headers.append('Accept','application/json');
  headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
  headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials','true');
  headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With');

  return this.http.post(apiUrl + type, credentials, {headers: headers});
}
```

In my ts file, I am running the API for adding the products to the cart and it is showing only one response in the console but it is calling 2 times because it is adding the 2 times the product and in the network in the chrome, it is calling 2 times.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The two networks calls in your chrome dev tool is showing OPTIONS in the first call's request method, then only POST for the second call is it?

Comment: @DriLLFreAK100. Yes.

Comment: That seems to be the expected behavior when you perform a CORS call to your backend server. It is just calling your API once though. Can refer to this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS. It mentioned that "...browsers "preflight" the request, soliciting supported methods from the server with an HTTP OPTIONS request method, and then, upon "approval" from the server, sending the actual request with the actual HTTP request method..."

Comment: As per your question, why is it adding 2 times, that you will have to take a look at your backend/server side code.

Comment: @DriLLFreAK100. headers.append('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); and let v = new FormData();
  for(var k in credentials)v.append(k,credentials[k]); Solved my problem,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Try This In Your **Service**:

```
usercartproducts(credentials, type) {
  var headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin' , '*');
  headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT');
  headers.append('Accept','application/json');
  headers.append('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials','true');
  headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With');

  let v = new FormData();
  for(var k in credentials)v.append(k,credentials[k]);
  return this.http.post(apiUrl + type, v, {headers: headers});
}
```

This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

because you implement yout API twice and your **If** condition must be wrong
change your ts like this.

```
 addtocartnew(detailsp) {
     if (detailsp.SelectedSize) {
       this.storage.get("ID").then((val) => {
         if (val) {

        let usercartnewdetails = {
          user_id: val,
          product_id: detailsp.id,
          size: detailsp.SelectedSize,
        };
        this.restProvider.usercartproducts(usercartnewdetails, 'user_cart/' + 
        detailsp.id + '/' + val + '/' + detailsp.SelectedSize).subscribe((data) => {
           console.log("One");
           this.responseEdit = data;
           console.log(this.responseEdit.msg);
           if (this.responseEdit.status === 'success') {
            this.presentToast(detailsp.product_name);
           }
           else {
             this.presentToasterror();
           }
         }
       });
     }
   })
 }
 else {
   this.storage.get("ID").then((val) => {
     if (val) {
       let usercartnewdetails = {
         user_id: val,
         product_id: detailsp.id,
       };
       this.restProvider.usercartproducts(usercartnewdetails, 'user_cart/' + 
       detailsp.id + '/' + val).subscribe((data) => {
         if (data) {
           console.log("Two");
           this.responseEdit = data;
           console.log(this.responseEdit.msg);
           if (this.responseEdit.status === 'success') {
             this.presentToast(detailsp.product_name);
           }
           else {
             this.presentToasterror();
           }
         }
       });
     }
   })
 }
}
```

change as per your condition and it will work.

Comment: No it is not wrong because I am checking this with the console.

Comment: ok, then have you console your all conditions which you implemented in this method and check which condition is wrong because your API calling twice.

Comment: I have edited your answer. It was working by doing these changes.